# When using sum case when 000 converts only 0

Tags: mysql, sql

In `table1` there is data like:

```
id  date        value
1   10/09       500
2   10/09       400
3   10/09       300
4   11/09       200
5   11/09       100
6   11/09       000
```

I want to set the data above within the show table:

```
date  | d1  |   d2   |  d3  |   d4  |   d5    | d6
----------------------------------------------------
10/09 | 500 |   400  |  300 |       |         |
----------------------------------------------------
11/09 |     |        |      |   200 |   100 |   000  
----------------------------------------------------
```

I am using the following sql query.

```
select date,
       sum(case when id = 1 then value end) as d1,
       sum(case when id = 2 then value end) as d2,
       sum(case when id = 3 then value end) as d3,
       sum(case when id = 4 then value end) as d4,
       sum(case when id = 5 then value end) as d5,
       sum(case when id = 6 then value end) as d6
from table1 GROUP BY date;
```

My problem arises when I am using the above query, In the output table, for `d6` column instead of `000` the value becomes only `0`. How to overcome this problem?

[Check SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20934a/1)

Comment: Numbers are numbers and `0` is represented as `0`, not `000`.

Comment: According to your fiddle, you are using MySQL not SQL Server.

Comment: Check the table in which you have saved the data. If you save numeric value 000=0 and if you save string '000' then that will save as '000'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a string value, then perhaps `max()` will do:

```
select date,
       max(case when id = 1 then value end) as d1,
       max(case when id = 2 then value end) as d2,
       max(case when id = 3 then value end) as d3,
       max(case when id = 4 then value end) as d4,
       max(case when id = 5 then value end) as d5,
       max(case when id = 6 then value end) as d6
from table1 
group by date;
```

You don't seem to actually want a `sum()`.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba80824/2) is a SQL Fiddle.  Notice that the values have to be inserted into the column as strings.